# Which URLLIB package to use with Python

Tags: python, urllib2, urllib

I am using Python.org version 2.7 64 bit on Windows Vista 64 bit. I am looking at the docs and sample code for URLLIB here:

https://docs.python.org/3/howto/urllib2.html
...and trying to submit the following code to access data from the Guardian API:

```
from urllib2 import Request, urlopen, URLError


response = urllib.request.urlopen('http://beta.content.guardianapis.com/search?tag=football%2Fworld-cup-2014&api-key=uexnxqm5bfwca4tn2m47wnhv')
html = response.read()
print html
```

This is not working and is kicking out the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Python27/stack", line 4, in <module>
    response = urllib.request.urlopen('http://beta.content.guardianapis.com/search?tag=football%2Fworld-cup-2014&api-key=uexnxqm5bfwca4tn2m47wnhv')
NameError: name 'urllib' is not defined
```

On page address for the documents it is pointing to a sub directory called 'urllib2', but the code examples are referencing a module called 'urllib'. On PYPI I can find no installation for 'urllib'.If I just run the import statement the code executes without causing an error, but with the rest of the code does not work.

Can anyone tell me which 'urllib' module I should have installed and/or why the code is producing this error?

Thanks

Comment: Read https://docs.python.org/2.7/howto/urllib2.html for Python 2.7.

Comment: You imported the name `urlopen`, **not** `urllib`, so use `response = urlopen('...')`.

Comment: You also linked to the Python 3 HOWTO, if you are using Python 2, use Python 2 documentation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using Python 2.7, but trying to follow a HOWTO written for Python *3*.

Use the [correct documentation instead](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/urllib2.html): https://docs.python.org/2/howto/urllib2.html, note how the URL contains a `2`, not a `3`, and the styling of the documentation differs materially.

Next, you are importing several names *from* the `urllib2` module:

```
from urllib2 import Request, urlopen, URLError
```

This means now have bound the name `urlopen` (together with `Request` and `URLError`), so you don't (and *can't*) use the `urllib2` module name in your code:

```
response = urlopen('http://beta.content.guardianapis.com/search?tag=football%2Fworld-cup-2014&api-key=uexnxqm5bfwca4tn2m47wnhv')
```

Answer (score 0):

Please use `requests` or if you really need `urllib` API, `urllib3` that is shipped with `requests`.

Everything else is has way too many gotchas, for example when it comes to ssl.

Comment: do you have some example syntax of what you mean? thanks